# Flatpak not available on 20.04?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, 20.04, flatpak

Just did a clean 20.04 install on my laptop.

Tried to install flatpak (cli), to install some additional software

Doesn't work:

```
 sudo apt install flatpak

Package flatpak is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
xdg-desktop-portal
```

Which is nonsense, because it is installed and flatpak doesn't work:

```
flatpak
flatpak: command not found
```

Why is flatpak not available in 20.04?

How do I install flatpak (cli)?

**UPDATE**
Flatpak is available after doing:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

(kudos to mook765)

Still:

- shouldn't this by done automatically after finishing an install
- the message that it is replaced by xdg-desktop-portal is confusing

Comment: `apt-cache search` shows it's [available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/flatpak) [for me](https://imgur.com/HB7l8Qx.png) on Xubuntu 20.04

Comment: Try to run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: @mook765. Thx, that did the trick. ;) Funny how I could have missed that, I update/install always by cli, but also strange IMHO that Ubuntu is not doing that by default after finishing a new install and a few restarts.

Comment: Duplicate marked question is totally different question, the comment of mook765 should be the answer.  You can easily run into this problem by having a fresh install, and trying to install flatpak after the first reboot. IMHO a fresh install should do a apt update in the end, of after first reboot, but maybe there are reason why that is not the default action.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update (and upgrade recommended) before you can install flatpak.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

(kudos to mook765)